# How do I rotate and duplicate a line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to recreate the line swirl in our compliment slip in Adobe Illustrator? I have been struggling for hours with transforming straight lines, creating waves, rotating, etc. but still can't get there?

[image]

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

Anne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is called the `Blend Tool`.

Here's how you use it:

- Create two lines using the `Pen Tool`:

[image: Two lines that are the starting point for the blend.]

- Activate the Blend Tool <kbd>W</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut, or you can click it on the Tools palette:

[image: Activate the Blend Tool!]

- Click on the two lines you want to blend.

[image: Creating a connection between the two lines]

- While the blend on your artboard is active, double-click the Blend tool icon to change the properties, or go into `Object` > `Blend` > `Blend Options...`.

[image: Changing the blend's properties]

That should do it! You can play with the stroke colors and positioning, but blending the lines together is the key to doing what you want.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you soooo much!!! The hours I've spent trying to do this! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a custom point of rotation, you're best off with the rotate tool (option+click to set your point of rotation). Then you `Transford again` to repeat it.

If you can just use one of the 9 standard points, I prefer to do this with a Transform effect.

[image: Draw your shape]

[image: Choose Effect > Distory & Transform > Transform ...]

Answer (score -1):

Arch tool with a stroke of maybe 1 or 2. Then Object -> Expand -> Expand Stroke

Now drop a gradient in

Now you'll want to do rotate by a small increment using the rotate command)

Now hit CTRL+D a bunch of times until you're happy with it.

Mirror across both axis. Or you could have made a more complex arc/pen to begin with.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply but I think maybe my picture isn't detailed enough. It's made up of 45 individual lines that converge and twist/flip/bend in the middle. I think the darker colour is caused by the density of the lines.

Comment: So skip step 1 and 2.